How to select file/dir in command mode completion with nvim-cmp?
In command-mode while using nvim-cmp, e.g., when you do :e ~/somedir/file but before pressing enter, file completion pops up. I can press tab if I happened to enter the prefix of a valid entry, and it will complete it. For example, if there is a file called file_something.txt then this works. If there are multiple entries, tab again to select the next. But if the file is instead named something_file.txt I can see the completion result, but pressing tab does nothing. How do I select the completion?
In constructing a minimal vimrc, I discovered this is really an nvim-cmp problem, so I've opened an issue there, with the repro vimrc. Thank you for the kind words in pointing this out. I will post the answer here when available.

I'm not sure I understand your use case. Maybe could elaborate on the example your are describing and share some screen shots? Are you able to repoduce your problem with vanilla Neovim (nvim --clean)? What is the simple init.vim that show the problem? Could you tell us the value of the options wildmenu and wildoptions? (Sorry for all these questions but I'm afraid I need the answer to understand and try to guide you:-/)

What you describe is not default behavior (at least not for Vim). You'd at least need to press Tab once to enable completion. Please [edit] and tell us how to reproduce the issue.
